# Что такое сень (в данном контексте) и как пишется Престол Уготованного (прописные-строчные)?

Tags: значение-слов, прописная-строчная

> Древняя мозаика расположена в конхе апсиды – на одной из самых важных
>   по своему назначению поверхностей. Апсида символизирует царство
>   чистого духа, а **конха – сень над святая святых** церкви, над её
>   алтарём. Алтарём, которым в католической церкви продолжает служить
>   **саркофаг мученика — прообраз Престола Уготованного**. Над ним, в конхе, всегда располагали изображения важнейших христианских сюжетов
>   и символов, а после 431 года, после принятия эдикта в Эфесе, – всегда
>   Богоматерь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***СЕНЬ*** = навес.

См. [**"Полный церковно-славянский словарь"**](http://www.slavdict.ru/_0700.htm) Дьяченко:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Слава, спасибо Вам большое, Вы здесь единственный человек с таким необъятным общекультурным уровнем. Про русский - помалкиваю. А что скажете про Престол Уготованного?

Comment: Пишут по-разному. Чаще употребляется написание с одной прописной -- _**Престол уготованный**_. В родительном падеже -- (прообраз)  _**Престола уготованного**_.

Comment: Спасибо. Не проверила Престол...